# Alter content types and site columns at the root site level after uploads

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, content-type, site-column, inheritance

Does anyone know how to add or delete content types, and site columns at the root-site level, after they have been used in libraries? If I have a content type that is used in several libraries (with documents of that content type already uploaded) is there a way to delete a site column within that content type at the root-site level, instead of going into each of those libraries and deleting it WITHOUT removing/changing the uploaded documents?

I do not want to make changes at the library level, because that would break my inheritance.

Thank you for your responses in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would have to go through and change all the documents/list items (or delete them) that use that content type then go back and delete the site columns of that site content type, then delete the site content type. What is it that you are really trying to accomplish? In other words, what is the business problem? There is probably a better way...

Comment: I apologize I thought I wrote it in my question, but I guess I didn't, I will edit that after this comment, but what I meant was I would like to accomplish this without removing/changing all the uploaded documents. The business problem is that we are currently developing a site in our test environment, and after implementing all the content types, site columns, etc our client informed us that there was a specific site column that shouldn't be there. Luckily only 5 documents had been uploaded so, deleting them, and making the change was easy. I am being proactive, i.e. 1000 documents instead

Comment: So delete the site column from the content type, then you can delete the site column from the site column gallery. When you delete the site column, it will delete the column for all the documents with that site content type.